# Как найти код чужой рекламы в шаблоне мобильной версии сайта на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите. Как найти код чужой рекламы в шаблоне мобильной версии сайта на WordPress? Реклама отображается в разных местах непосредственно в карточки товара.  Больше нигде не отображается.

Как найти это код и убить? Заранее спасибо за советы и рекомендации.

Да, Woocommerce! сайт: [tcs-ag.ru](http://tcs-ag.ru)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Woocommerce ???

Comment: Лучше швырни линк на сайт, и ткни носом в рекламу, быстрее получишь ответ

Comment: Попробовать разыскать php-файлы, содержащие что-нибудь вроде base64_encode - подобную рекламу часто шифруют.

Comment: смените провайдера. или перейдите на https: https://meduza.io/shapito/2017/11/22/megafon-nachal-pokazyvat-svoyu-reklamu-na-chuzhih-saytah-chtoby-ot-etogo-izbavitsya-pridetsya-zvonit-v-podderzhku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С вашим сайтом все в порядке. Рекламу вставляет ваш мобильный провайдер - MegaFon.

В качестве защитно меры проще всего перейти на https с флагом [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) и опцией Preload - это лишит провайдера возможности влезать в траффик.

Comment: Это всё временно. Пока вы будете так "защищаться" они придумают как внедряться в https (благо тех. решения существуют) и протащат свои законы, разрешающие им это делать. И тогда пострадают не только ваши сатийки с рекламами, но и куда более серьёзные вещи. Нужно судиться с этими козлами. Для этого существуют [ст 272-274 УК РФ](http://www.consultant.ru/document/cons_doc_LAW_10699/4398865e2a04f4d3cd99e389c6c5d62e684676f1/)

Comment: @SeVlad как-то не слышал о тех. решениях, которые позволяют обойти preloaded hsts. можно ссылку? По поводу судиться - абонент сам поставил подпись под соответствующим пунктом в договоре. Но попробуйте, расскажете о результатах.

Comment: 1. договор совершено не причём - есть нарушение закона. И есть успешные решения судов (правда, по др статьям). 2. Не "обойти preloaded hsts", а внедриться в https.

Comment: @SeVlad ну ок, покажите мне способ "внедриться в https"

Comment: Тебе в гуглояндексы. Напр по "mitmproxy"

Comment: @SeVlad уф, а я то уже думал, что там действительно про "внедрение в https" и крутые хакерские технологии, а оказалось что это все про обычный https debugging proxy, который требует ручной установки root certificate на клиентское устройство.

Comment: Вот как раз в договоре они могут обязать прописать установить свой сертификат. Или даже не прописывать явно.. (а иначе просто не будет работать интернет). И это не будет нарушать никакие законы. И к этому скоро придёт если будете так "защищаться".

Answer (score -2):

Как бы делал я .
Перенести проект на локалхост. Один из методов - это установить себе ***Total Commander***. Дальше, при помощи консоли  браузера определить родителя рекламы,.т.е. селектора, который может относиться непосредственно к шаблону , а не к баннеру.
В TC зайти в свою тему и в поиске файлов можно найти рекламу по тексту: *Инструменты==> Поиск файлов...* или **CTRL+F7** . Нужно отметить галочку "С текстом", дальше справа все кроме XML. В итоге в найденных файлах также найти строку, где есть селектор и там смотреть, где находится кодированная ссылка.